# Arduino L239D RC-Car

Tags: bluetooth, arduino

I want to build an Arduino car controller via Bluetooth and smartphone. My problem is that the RC-motors don't work as they should.

```cpp
//Kann auch ENABLE EN1 und EN2 
//L293 statt L293D, weil 1A statt 0,5A und wird weniger heiß, ist aber größer, die 0V in seiner Schematics ist Hitzeableiter

int IN1  = 12;
int IN2  = 13;
int schalter = 4; 
int gas = 0;
void setup() {
    pinMode(IN1, OUTPUT); 
    pinMode(IN2, OUTPUT); 
}
void loop() {
    digitalWrite(IN1, LOW);
    digitalWrite(IN2, HIGH);
    delay(2000);
    digitalWrite(IN2, LOW);
    delay(2000);
}
```

If I connect a battery directly to the motor, it spins. But over the L293D driver nothing works. But when I measure the outputs of the L293D that would be connected to the motor, the output is just fine.

Comment: It would be useful, if you would show your wiring. But if the problem is with the wiring, the problem is not about programming and off-topic here.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that i didn't connect the 0V/Ground from the L293 to the Arduino.
Code was fine.